# Firebase database rules only two out of three conditions work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have "UID" database (uid root for each user).
I try to share "uid" roots between users, and i want to give read access to "UID" root in one of three cases:
1. The user who access is the owner.
2. The user who access is located in "UID\PERMITTED_USERS" of target root.
3. The user who access is located in "UID\TEMP_USERS" of target root.

To accomplish this I created next rule:

```
".read" : "$uid === auth.uid || (root.child(root.child(auth.uid).child('PRE_SHARE').val()).child('TEMP_USERS').hasChild(root.child(auth.uid).child('TEMP_PERMIT').val()) || root.child(root.child(auth.uid).child('CURRENT_SHARE').val()).child('PERMITTED_USERS').hasChild(auth.uid))"
```

But I was disapointed to discover that only the first two conditions are checked, and the third is not. (I changed the order of the conditions and every time I could access using the first two in a row).

Is there a way to solve this?

EDIT:

Adding db example:
[image: sharing user]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the sample database?

Comment: I am pretty sceptical about the situation because it is unlikely to have bug in the expression evaluator. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Anyway you can give a try with using parentheses around the second and third expression therefore it should evaluate both of them.

Comment: PRE_SHARE id is within the auth id ?

Comment: Yes, PRE_SHARE is located in auth id of the user who is trying to access the shared database. The idea was to hold for the user who access the name of the share and the rule can use it to know where to look.

Comment: what is the id which is trailed by '......73'

Comment: My mistake i fabricated the view in real time it is NjaXMNqUaCVgUE9C0F4VmtG3PWM2

Comment: how are you accessing the id "hbvc9OaAMPbWDEf7uo10Hjc1bw73" because that is failing your rule

Comment: I updated the question with the correct view.

Comment: Each rule separatly works. But the OR combination fails...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154405/discussion-between-andrey-dobrikov-and-mzeus-bolt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lots of tests I found the problem. My code deletes PRE_SHARE as well as TEMP_USERS, and when rule tries to access val() of non existent PRE_SHARE it gets null pointer exception. Too bad Firebase doesn't write this exception, it would save me lots of time...

```
".read" : "$uid === auth.uid || 
                  (root.child(auth.uid).hasChild('PRE_SHARE') && 
                  root.child(root.child(auth.uid).child('PRE_SHARE').val()).hasChild('TEMP_USERS') && 
                  root.child(auth.uid).hasChild('TEMP_PERMIT') && 
                  root.child(root.child(auth.uid).child('PRE_SHARE').val()).child('TEMP_USERS').hasChild(root.child(auth.uid).child('TEMP_PERMIT').val())) || 
                  (root.child(auth.uid).hasChild('CURRENT_SHARE') && 
                  root.child(root.child(auth.uid).child('CURRENT_SHARE').val()).hasChild('PERMITTED_USERS') && 
                  root.child(root.child(auth.uid).child('CURRENT_SHARE').val()).child('PERMITTED_USERS').hasChild(auth.uid))"
```